# openApiGenerate don`t generate Models

Tags: build.gradle, gradle-plugin, openapi-generator

I use gradle plugin

```
id "org.openapi.generator" version "5.1.1"
```

and task in gradle.plugin

```
openApiGenerate {
    generatorName = "kotlin"
    inputSpec = "$rootDir/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/API.v1.yaml".toString()
    outputDir = "$rootDir/generated".toString()
    apiPackage = "org.openapi.example.api"
    invokerPackage = "org.openapi.example.invoker"
    modelPackage = "org.openapi.example.model"
    configOptions = [
  

      dateLibrary: "java8"
]
```

}

when I call **gradlew openApiGenerate**

I got

```
Execution failed for task ':openApiGenerate'.
> There were issues with the specification. The option can be disabled via validateSpec (Maven/Gradle) or --skip-validate-spec (CLI).
   | Error count: 244, Warning count: 0
  Errors:
      
  -attribute paths.'/v1/pet/{name}/home/'(post).responses.406.content is unexpected
  -attribute paths.'/v1/pet/{name}/home'(post).responses.400.content is unexpected
  ..........
```

But if I call in CLI version my yaml generate Models and API

Why it call that Exceptions?

Unfortunatelly, I can not add here even a part of my yaml, because site told me "ït looks you add a lot of code"

If I add

```
skipValidateSpec         = true
```

I get only API without Models. Why?

Comment: we need to see the spec , there is no way we can help without the code . maybe try https://codeshare.io/ ?